# using map function in react native to render values dynamically from textinput

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

What I am trying to achieve is a shipping list, anytime a user input a shipping list and selects from the list of addresses dropdown, a box appears below with the new shipping address
Then the search input is hidden 
If the user presses ‘add new’ button, the search input reappears and then the user can input another shipping address and another box appears just under the other box with the new address
Also, onpress of the delete button ‘x’ that particular shipping address gets deleted while the other one(s) remain.

any suggestions or corrections

below are my code

ShippingList.js

```
    class ShippingList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          shippingAddressSearch: true,
          shippingAddListShow: false,
          shippingAddress: '',
          shippingAddressList: [],
        };
      }

      handleLocationSelected => (data, { geometry }) => {
        const {
          location: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }
        } = geometry;
        const shippingAddress = data.structured_formatting.main_text;

        this.setState({
          shippingAddress,
          destination: {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            title: shippingAddress,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0143,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0134,
          },
          shippingAddressSearch: false,
        });
      };

      render() {
        const { shippingAddressSearch, shippingAddress, shippingAddListShow } = this.state;
        return (
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
            <View style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>                      
              <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
              <View style={styles.screenHeaderWrapper}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                   style={addNewContainer}
                   onPress={this.addNewShippingAddress}
                >
                 <Text style={addNewTextStyle}>Add New<\Text>
                 <\TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                {shippingAddressSearch && (
                <LocationSearch
                  onLocationSelected={this.handleLocationSelected}
                />)}

                  //this is the box I want to display onlocation selected
                  <View style={styles.locationWrapper}>
                    <AntDesign
                      name='home'
                      size={20}
                      color='#535BFE'
                      style={styles.leftNavIcon}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.locationTextStyle}>{shippingAddress}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.handleRemoveShippingAddress}
                      style={styles.rightNavIcon}
                    >
                      <AntDesign
                        name='closecircle'
                        size={20}
                        color='#AEB4C0'
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ))}
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      AndroidSafeArea: {
        flex: 1,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: '#F9F9FB',
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
      },
      inputWrapper: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 0.9,
      },

      screenHeaderWrapper: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 0.1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#F9F9FB',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
      },
      addNewTextContainer: {
        flex: 0.5,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
      },
      addNewtextStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
        color: '#535BFE',
      },
      inputContainer: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 0.9,
        backgroundColor: '#F9F9FB',
        padding: 20,
      },
      locationWrapper: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderRadius: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        shadowRadius: 10,
        padding: 15,
      },
      leftNavIcon: {
        flex: 0.1,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        textAlign: 'left',
      },
      rightNavIcon: {
        flex: 0.1,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
      },
      locationTextStyle: {
        color: '#34495E',
        fontSize: 16,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 0.8,
      },
    });

    export default ShippingList;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you reduced this to only the relevant code.

Comment: I have reduced the code as you adviced, your help would be appreciated